# Is there a tool to see every WordPress site that's using a particular plugin?

Tags: plugins, third-party-applications

Is there a tool to see every WordPress site that's using a particular plugin? For example: if I wanted to know every website in the world that is currently (or historically) using Yoast SEO.

I realize this would probably be a third party tool, so I don't know if it's appropriate for this forum. But, I figured it's a good place to ask seeing as it's related to WordPress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think Beyond Multisite is going to do it.

when you look at a site that is using Yoast you will see that it loads 'yoast.js'

The best idea I have is to use a site like publicwww.com (free for first 3M pages) to provide a list of all sites that it knows  also using that file.

https://publicwww.com/websites/yoast.js/

That link should work.

This may not be ALL the sites it is only the sites that the page has crawled / discovered.

There are prob other sites with this ability.

Hope this helps.

Cheers,

Comment: Hi @Falz, you are correct that Beyond Multisite doesn't do this. It's a plugin only suited to manage your internal network of "multi-sites". Nothing beyond any sites you own. Unfortunately, the plugin I'm trying see doesn't use an identifiable .js file. So, your suggestion isn't applicable in this use case. Can you think of any other tools that can see ALL WordPress sites with a particular plugin activated? Thanks.

Comment: hi @grizzam527 do you have an example site using yoast? My initial search shows there being a script file yoast.js? and there are millions of sites also using that js so I assumed that was a good indicator I was on the right path.

Comment: Hi, I see that you can search for any substring which solves my issue! I was thinking it had to be a .js file, but you can do /plugin/my-plugin/ or whatever you want. Great suggestion, thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

try BeyondMultisite which offers several features, where one of them does exactly what you want to do.
rdgs/Gunnar